# Trying to set canvas width and video width but answer with object objetct

Tags: javascript, webrtc

I'm trying to modify the video and audio default settings that I'm recording but for any reason I don't know, It doesn't work.
What I get at the beginning I start the record is:

```
started recording audio stream.
sample-rate 48000
buffer-size 4096
started recording [Object Object] stream.
sample-rate 48000
buffer-size 4096
```

The main issue is "started recording" which returns `[Object Object]`. It should return width and height sizes. It seems I'm not setting correctly the mandatory variable.

Here bellow I paste my code:

```
var video = $('preview')[0],
    audio,
    fileName,
    replay,
    blob,
    timer,
    streaming,
    isFirefox = !!navigator.mozGetUserMedia,
    recordAudio,
    recordVideo,
    progress,
    upload_bar,
    seconds,
    video_constraints = { mandatory: { minWidth: 1280, minHeight: 720, minFrameRate: 30}, optional: [] };

//If getUserMedia is soported by our browser and we allow to use it, our video tag will show the stream we're recording.
function success(stream) {
    'use strict';

    video = $('#preview')[0];

    video.src = window.URL.createObjectURL(stream);

    video.play();

    video.muted = true;

    if (!isFirefox) {
        window.stream = stream;
    } else {
        audio = document.querySelector('audio');
        streaming = stream;
    }

    $('#start-camara').hide();
    $('#round-record').css('display', 'block');

    $('.record-actions').css('justify-content', 'center');

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#preview').css('width', 'auto');
    }, 1255);

    $('#round-record > path').on('click', function () {
        if (!isFirefox) {
            $('#splitbar-pause').css('display', 'block');
        }

        if (!video.src) {
            window.alert("there must be an error with your video");
            return;
        } else {
            $('#square-stop').css('display', 'block');
            $('#round-record').css('display', 'none');
        }

        countdown();

        recordAudio = new RecordRTC(stream, {
            // bufferSize: 16384,
            onAudioProcessStarted: function () {
                if (!isFirefox) {
                    recordVideo.startRecording();
                }
            }
        });

        recordVideo = new RecordRTC(stream, {
            type: video_constraints
        });

        recordAudio.startRecording();
    });


}

// Sets a poster error when there's no posibility to load the camera
function error(e) {
    'use strict';

    if (!video.hasAttribute("poster")) {
        video.setAttribute("poster", "img/nocamera.png");
    }
}

// Check the webRTC library compatible with the browser
function checkCompatibility() {
    'use strict';

    return !!(navigator.getUserMedia ||
                 navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                 navigator.mozGetUserMedia ||
                 navigator.msGetUserMedia);
}

function startCamera() {
    'use strict';

    if (!checkCompatibility()) {
        error();
    }

    if (!window.stream && navigator.getUserMedia) {
        navigator.getUserMedia({
            audio: true,
            video: video_constraints
        }, success, error);
    } else {
        error();
    }
}
```

Could someone help me with this?

Thanks in advice.

Comment: :light-bulb: A good start would be to add the relevant code. There is a reason that posters are asked to supply a MCVE. (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Without seeing the code that outputs the message in the first place (`started recording [Object Object] stream`) one is left to decide whether or not to play a guessing game.

Comment: @Kaiido - There are many reasons why users don't post MVCEs. Almost exclusively, these relate to the inconvenience this imposes on the question-asker. As always, one gets better results when one makes it easy for others to give help. :shrugs:

Comment: @Kaiido - Fair enough point with regards to jQuery, But still, it doesn't stop people asking questions about its use from posting an MCVE. Thank-you for explaining to me that the output comes from library code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the second argument to [`recordRTC(stream, options)`](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC#record-video) should be `{type: 'video'}` if you only want to record the video.

Here you dont pass this `video` argument, so I think it tries to record a `mandatory`, which may fail.

To [constrain the width/height](https://github.com/muaz-khan/RecordRTC#user-content-how-to-set-video-widthheight) of the recorded video, the options should look like

```
var options = {
   type: 'video',  // Mandatory STRING
   video: {
      width: 320,
      height: 240
   },
   canvas: {
      width: 320,
      height: 240
   }
};

var recordVideo = RecordRTC(MediaStream, options);
```

You can even set width/height instead:

```
var options = {
   type: 'video',     // Mandatory STRING
   width: 1920,
   height: 1280
};

var recordVideo = RecordRTC(MediaStream, options);
```

Comment: I wasn't understanding at all where to place the options. Now it's fine! Thanks!